# interior angles of irregular polygon with angles > 180

Tags: c++, math, vector-graphics

I'm trying to calculate the values shown in the picture in red i.e. the interior angles.

I've got an array of the points where lines intersect and have tried using the dot-product but it only returns the smallest angles. I need the full range of internal angles (0-359) but can't seem to find much that meets this criteria.

[image: arrow]

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730855/how-to-compute-directional-angle-between-two-2d-vectors-in-matlab/28732160#28732160) has the answer in the MATLAB language. I think you should still be able to follow it, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your angles are in standard counterclockwise format, the following should work:

```
void angles(double points[][2], double angles[], int npoints){
    for(int i = 0; i < npoints; i++){
        int last = (i - 1 + npoints) % npoints;
        int next = (i + 1) % npoints;
        double x1 = points[i][0] - points[last][0];
        double y1 = points[i][1] - points[last][1];
        double x2 = points[next][0] - points[i][0];
        double y2 = points[next][1] - points[i][1];
        double theta1 = atan2(y1, x1)*180/3.1415926358979323;
        double theta2 = atan2(y2, x2)*180/3.1415926358979323;
        angles[i] = (180 + theta1 - theta2 + 360);
        while(angles[i]>360)angles[i]-=360;
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you are using some sort of data structure for your points, you will want to replace `double points[][2]` and references to it with references to your data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain full angle range `(-Pi..Pi)` with atan2 function:

```
atan2(crossproduct, dotproduct)
```